# Should we need to download the SSL certificate for Mobile Application to access secure web services

Tags: android, iphone, blackberry, mobile, windows-mobile

It's a general question for Mobile Application platform,I want to clarify one thing regarding SSL certificate.

If we will working with secure web services in any platform of Mobile Application, Should we need to download the SSL certificate for Mobile?

Without SSL certificate we can acess any secure web service in Mobile Application.

Please, anybody clarify about SSL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your connection API will handle this swiftly. There is no need to manually download SSL certificates. Just create proper URL and make proper request. Rest of the complexity should be handled by connection APIs itself.

Even if they require to download, they will prompt user while communication is going on.